# Unable to access SOLR server admin page

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to SOLR. I am building SOLR from source using solr-5.0.0-src.tgz. After running

```
ant compile
```

at solr-5.0.0/, I run

```
bin/solr start
```

at solr-5.0.0/solr/. And it says

```
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983 [/]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=20151). Happy searching!
```

However, when visiting http://localhost:8983/solr/, I receive HTTP ERROR

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:
Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://
```

And

```
bin/solr status
```

gives

```
Found 1 Solr nodes: 

Solr process 20151 running on port 8983
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
```

I wonder if this is the reason admin page is unavailable? If so, how I could solve the problem. If not, what is it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

change to solr directory and run:

```
ant server
```

Then restart the server

```
bin/solr stop && bin/solr start
```

Check that everything is working:

```
bin/solr status
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the full stack trace...
Here it is    ....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/solr/util/SolrCLI : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.  Program will exit.
```

To fix the problem you need to upgrade the java ...to J2SE 7

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Abhijit. I already upgraded  to jdk 7, but that didn't help.

Comment: @markjin1990 : yes... I too tried upgrading it to jdk 7...it still gives the same error...

Comment: @markjin1990 : figured it out ...Please make sure that both JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables are updated to 7...                               export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75                                                  I set it and removed the error...

Comment: Hi, Abhijit. When I run solr in foreground, it throws FileIOException on solr/server/webapps/solr.war. The file solr/server/webapps/solr.war is missing. The trick is run `ant server` under solr/. Problem solved, thanks!